# Filtered Rows in React Material Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, row

I have two `javascript` files (`Tableau.js` & `Explorateur.js`):

```
#Tableau
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchApi } from "reducers/generalReducer";
import { apiMelodi } from "utils/webServiceUtils";
import { MaterialReactTable } from "material-react-table";

const Tableau = ({ datasetId }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [donnees, setDonnees] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (datasetId) {
      dispatch(
        fetchApi(
          apiMelodi,
          api => api.get(`/data/${datasetId}?maxResult=20`),
          data => {
            setDonnees(data.observations);
          }
        )
      );
    }
  }, [dispatch, datasetId]);
  if (donnees.length === 0) {
    return "pas de données";
  }
  const columnsMulti = () => {
    return donnees[0].dimensions
      .map(dim => {
        return {
          header: dim.concept.code,
          accessorKey: dim.concept.code,
        };
      })
      .concat([
        {
          header: "Time period",
          accessorKey: "timePeriod",
          filterVariant: "text",
        },
      ])
      .concat(
        (donnees[0]?.measures || []).map(m => {
          return {
            header: `${m.measure.code} ${m.measure.measureType.code}`,
            accessorKey: `${m.measure.code}#${m.measure.measureType.code}`,
          };
        })
      );
  };

  const dataMulti = () => {
    donnees.forEach(o => {
      o.dimensions.forEach(d => {
        o[d.concept.code] = d.value?.code;
      });
      o?.measures?.forEach(m => {
        o[`${m.measure.code}#${m.measure.measureType.code}`] = m.value;
      });
    });
  };

  dataMulti();

  return (
    <MaterialReactTable
      columns={columnsMulti()}
      manualFiltering
      manualSorting
      data={donnees}
      initialState={{ pagination: { pageSize: 25, pageIndex: 2 }, showColumnFilters: true }}
      defaultColumn={{ minSize: 1, maxSize: 6, size: 5.5 }}
      enableColumnFilterModes
      enableColumnOrdering
      enableSorting
      enableColumnActions={false}
      muiTableHeadCellProps={{
        sx: {
          xs: "11.5px",
          sm: "12px",
          md: "13.5px",
          lg: "14px",
          xl: "15px",
          fontSize: "11.5px",
        },
      }}
      muiTableBodyCellProps={{
        sx: {
          fontSize: "12px",
        },
      }}
      muiTableFooterRowProps={{
        sx: {
          fontSize: "9.75px",
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Tableau;

#Explorateur
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import FilAriane from "structure/FilAriane";
import Titre from "structure/Titre";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Tableau from "pages/explorateur/Tableau";
import { useState } from "react";

const Catalogue = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { datasetId } = useParams();

  return (
    <Grid container justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
      <FilAriane idMenuSelection={1} liens={[{ libelle: "Explorateur" }]} />
      <Titre titre={t("explorateur.titre")} />
      <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center">
        <Grid item sx={{ width: 1023.9 }}>
          <Tableau datasetId={datasetId} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Catalogue;
```

I can't filter my rows according to the input value in the column filter, can only filter manually. I think i need to pass a  `filteredData` with a `setFilteredData` using the `useState('')` function, and pass that function with the filtered data into a specific MaterialReactTable property. It's the first time I do this with the material react table library. Do you have any clue ?

thank you Stack community

I tried the manual filter, but it's not enough, I want to sort only the row values of the filter, so that my filter can be efficient [image]